# Broken Hyperlink to Chapter Title with KOMA-Script Class "scrreprt" and Modified "beforeskip"-Value

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, chapters, koma-script, scrreprt

I realize an unexpected behavior of the hyperlink to a chapter title in the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`.

I modified the `\chapter` command Using the `\RedeclareSectionCommands` command available since KOMA-Script version 3.15
In more detail, to change the vertical position of the chapter title, I set the options `beforeskip`.

Using the MWE below, it can be realized that the `hyperref` target anchor is not adapted to match the new title position.
The subsequent screenshots taken after the chapter was selected in the index of my PDF-viewer illustrate this behavior:

- `beforeskip=0pt`:
  [image: 0pt]
- `beforeskip=-10pt`:
  [image: -10pt]
- `beforeskip=-20pt`:
  [image: -20pt]
- `beforeskip=-30pt`:
  [image: -30pt]

The `hyperref` target seems to be too low!
Is this the intended behavior? And is there a way to adapt the link in such way that the results look always as in the first case (`beforeskip=0pt`)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[version=3.26]{scrreprt}

% Packages
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Change Chapter Title Location
\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
   beforeskip=-20pt, % Change this to see the different Hyperlink behavior
   afterindent=false,
]{chapter}

% Document Dummy Content
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example Chapter One}
\blindtext
\chapter{Example Chapter Two}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: the chapter command first issues the \refstepcounter (which sets the anchor), and then moves the chapter up by the -20pt and so the anchor is too low. I don't see a way to adapt this in the hyperref code, so you should report it to the KOMA maintainer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond and explanation!   
I leave this question open in case someone comes up with a workaround.